# How to fix ionic 2 Apple Mach-O Linker error?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic2

I'm building an ionic 2 app, and I can build the app with ionic build ios and I get no erros, but on xcode when I build my application I get the following error.

Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

How can I fix this?

**Here is my system information**

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0

Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0

Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1

Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4

ios-deploy version: 1.9.0

OS: macOS Sierra

Node Version: v6.9.4

Xcode Version: Xcode 8.3 Build version 8E162

Answer (score 30):

You are probably opening the `.xcodeproj` on Xcode, try opening the `.xcworkspace`. This fixed this error for me.

Comment: Solved my problem, this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue, spent almost a day trying to figure out what was causing it. For me the following solved it. Everything was working fine on ios@4.3.1, but on 4.5.3, I got this annoying error.

Check if this plugin "**cordova-plugin-console**" is there in the plugins folder. If it is there, remove it. Then it started building without any errors.

**ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console**

Answer (score 8):

Look for a file named `libPods-AppName.a` in `Frameworks` directory
where `AppName` is your app name.

Deleting it fixes it in most cases.

Take a look at the screenshot for reference.

[Quick Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPRpZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: My project uses Ionic v1**

I had the same error and, once I had added a Android-only plugin, I thought that it was the cause of the error - I was wrong (so, ignore this cause if you think the same as I).

After some search I found the truly cause of the error: the cordova-ios version (4.5). I followed the steps suggested [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12849#issuecomment-329971907) and I solve this issue.

Steps:

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios@4.4.0
ionic cordova platform
```

Last step is used to check if *ios@4.4.0* is actually the installed version.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Super @Rochadsouza you saved my time

Comment: @Raghuram glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

In your platforms folder for ios, there are both .xcodeproj and .xcworkspace files. Open the /platforms/ios/.xcworkspace.

Answer (score -3):

I found the issue that was causing this error.

On the config.xml file on the  tag I had the email with my@email.com and you cannot have the .com on the email. I removed and it works fine now.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What? what email are you using? gmail, outlook have .com as the ending

Comment: @Mani, on the config.xml file you have a property <author email=""......> if you enter your email address with the .com at the end I was getting this error message, once I remove the .com from the email it works fine.